# Wicket jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wicket

I'm using Wicket 6 with bootstrap integration and want to use jQuery functions but I'm not able to get them to work. Any jQuery code I try in Wicket doesn't work.

For example I'm doing it in an AjaxLink in the onClick method with....

```
target.appendJavaScript("$( \"wicketExtensionsBreadCrumbBar\" ).text( \"<p>This is a test.</p>\" );");
```

I also tried other functions for example for repositioning a div...

No function there. It feels like that jQuery isn't active but Firebug tells me that some jquery wicket files are loaded.

Any idead why jQuery isn't working?

Comment: if that code gets placed in head need to use a ready handler so elements exist when code runs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$("wicketExtensionsBreadCrumbBar") is broken selector because there is no HTML element with name `wicketExtensionsBreadCrumbBar`. You need either $(".wicketExtensionsBreadCrumbBar") for CSS class selection or $("#wicketExtensionsBreadCrumbBar") - selection by ID.